# Get last insert or update store action

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `ExampleRepository`, who receives validated array, store it in db with some modification, and responses inserted/updated object. It uses function:

ExampleRepository:

```
public function store($validtedData)
{
    //some code
    return MyExampleModel::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id], [$modifiedData]);
}
```

Is it possible to understand, which action was used on object (update or insert)? I mean:

`do not copy code below, such function not existence`

```
$example = $this->exampleRepository->store($validatedData);

if ($example->justNewlyCreated())
    //do something
else
    //do something else
```

I don't need object_id nor other data, but only action used on object to store in db

Comment: So you want to known if an insert happend or an update happend? Could you elaborate why you would need this?

Comment: @MaartenDev Thank you! This is exactly I looking for, but unfortunately I didn't found it before I created the question